# Using BehavioralSubject Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I have 2 components and a service. BehaviorSubject in the service class has default values and also it pulls in data from an API. The first component gets the latest data which is pulled from the API, but the second component only displays the default values. What could be wrong in my code. Plz advise!

```
export class WebService {
  public btnsOnResponse; //activates buttons when server responds positive
  BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
  private stats = new BehaviorSubject<IStats>({
    date: this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy'),
    answeringMachine:0,
    hangUp:0,
    conversations:0
  });
  public stats$ = this.stats.asObservable();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getStatsbyDate('04-03-2018');
  }
```

Components:
1st Component

```
export class StatsComponent {
  public stats: IStats;
  constructor(private webService: WebService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.webService.stats$.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data !== null) { this.stats = data; } 
      // else { this.webService.stats.next(this.stats); }
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

[image: Console.log]
2nd Component

```
export class ChartsComponent {
  private stats: IStats;
  constructor(private webService: WebService) {
    this.webService.stats$.subscribe((data: IStats) => {
      this.stats = data;      
    })
    console.log(this.stats);  
  }
```

Comment: `console.log` is executed before assignment inside subscription, that's why you're getting the initial value

Comment: Thanks @Wilhelm, I put it inside the subscription, still it doesn't get the latest values.

Comment: try to remove `stats$`, change `stats` to public, and in `this.getStatsbyDate `set `stats.next(result)`, you don't need another Observable.

Comment: Please fork this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pu7uxz?file=app%2Ftest.service.ts and show how you manage to get such issue. p.s. - constructor is supposed to be used only for the DI

Comment: Thanks @J.D. I checked your code, Its exaclty the same way I did it. I editted my post with an image, do you have any idea why the console log runs twice from the same component, the first value are the default values from the behavioral Subject and the second values are the values from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're having is that you are defining a BehaviorSubject and the initial values that are sent through the Observables pipeline, but you are not actually pushing the next set of values through that pipeline whenever you receive the data back from the API ([more reading from RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)). Here is your updated code example:

```js
export class WebService {
  public btnsOnResponse; //activates buttons when server responds positive
  BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
  private stats = new BehaviorSubject<IStats>({
    date: this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy'),
    answeringMachine:0,
    hangUp:0,
    conversations:0
  });
  public stats$ = this.stats.asObservable();
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // I am going to assume that the this.getStatsByDate() returns an Observable of some kind.
    this.getStatsbyDate('04-03-2018')
      .subscribe(
        // You needed to subscribe to this function call and then call the .onNext() function in order to pass in the next set of data to your this.stats$ Observable.
        (val: any) => this.stats$.onNext(val)
      );
  }
  
  // I am guessing that you have an implementation of the this.getStatsByDate() function somewhere here, since you didn't include it in your original post.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @th3n3wguy. This is the way I have the getStatsByDate method now, There is already a subscription in there with the latest results being passed.   getStatsbyDate(date) {
    this.http.get<IStats>(this.BASE_URL + '/stats/' + date)
      .subscribe((data: IStats) => {
        this.stats.next(data);
        this.btnsOnResponse = true;
      });
  }

Comment: Anybody here who could help me with this?

Comment: @Sumchans => I am guessing that this solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you run another `async` operation, as you wrote in your comment - `this.http.get<IStats>`. That async function has a callback - `subscribe()` with functions in it. Because it is `async` and JavaScript is single-threated, Angular continues building your application (components etc.) while that callback is being placed in so called "Callback Queue". It fires only after Call stack (normal Javascript functions) is empty - so when Angular finishes building your app (in general). So that means that  `this.stats.next(data)` is being fired **after** you subscribe your BehaviourSubject, so you get one initial value and later comes another.

You can remove that `async` and `next` other object:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // this.getStatsbyDate('04-03-2018');
    this.stats.next({
      date: this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy'),
      answeringMachine:100,
      hangUp:100,
      conversations:100
    });)
  }
```

You should get only the last value.

Comment: Thanks @J.D I got the whole thing by using Subject instead of Behavior Subject.